# Simple service that allows you to log HTTP requests?

Tags: http, logging, httprequest

Are there any simple services that will give you a URL that you can send HTTP requests to and see a log of **all** requests that have been made and what headers/data they contained?

I'll probably end up just throwing a few lines of code together myself, was just wondering if something was already out there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after 1 minute google use (without any warranty) :

http://www.aditsu.net/tools/HTTP_request_analyzer?a=100

Comment: I need something that allows you to see requests that have been made from other sources. So some kind of a unique URL, where any request made to it is stored, and you can visit the URL in a browser to see all requests that have been made to it.